# jsx script in which information from after effects is leaked

Tags: python, scripting, jsx

I am an intermediate editor, so I've been studying after effects for about three months now, and I've begun downloading present packs, cc, project files, and so on. I also recently downloaded a script, and I read the terms and conditions of the script creator, and I found

**"If your computer is connected to the Internet, the script will
record each action you perform on it and transmit anonymized data
associated with those actions to one of my servers. This enables you
to monitor your own statistics by visiting
https://uwu2x.alixz.ovh/stats or by clicking on the “UPDATE” button
of the script.
I'm engaging in this data collection and analysis process because I
have a keen interest in gathering and dissecting extensive datasets.
While scrutinizing data from this particular script may not yield
significant insights, for my script createLayersFaster, such
analysis holds greater relevance. It would indeed be a prudent
concept to train an AI using this data. For instance, the AI could
learn to deduce the types of layers the user intends to generate
based on their selections of existing layers.
By clicking on the "Update" button within the script, you can access
additional information." What the hell is happing" **

I want to address information leaks using a script that I downloaded for After Effects.